# A win32 vs x64 code comparison

Tags: c, 64-bit

I was playing around with some code for a while :

```
    int n;
    char *ptr;
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    ptr = (char *) &n; // pointer to the integer
    printf("\na[0]=%p",*ptr); // print the values at the next 4 memory locations
    printf("\na[1]=%p",*(ptr+1));
    printf("\na[2]=%p",*(ptr+2));
    printf("\na[3]=%p",*(ptr+3));
```

this code gives me a clean output of

```
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF
```

for a input of -1 on win32 settings in VisualC++ '12.

However when I compile this code for a x64 architecture i get -

```
00000000FFFFFFFF
00000000FFFFFFFF
00000000FFFFFFFF
00000000FFFFFFFF
```

for the same input value of -1. The size of integer is same across both the architectures. 
My question is why the memory layout is not all F's throughout the 4 locations ?

Comment: You are misusing `%p`. Use `%x` instead.

Comment: @cnicutar that is the whole point. You get to see the MSBs filled with 0s if you use %p as it prints the contents over that location.

Comment: `%p` wants a `void *` and you're passing a `char` (that gets promoted to an `int`).

Comment: @cnicutar Maybe i am getting it all wrong. But how does this change anything when I switch from x86 to x64. I believe that a -1 should be stored as all F's in the memory for both the architectures. Can you tell me the correct way of doing it. Actually seeing it if that is the case.

Comment: Don't you see a problem with the fact that you're printing **a byte** and getting `FFFFF` (16 bits) ? Grandma, what big bytes you have!

Comment: @Samboy786: `%p` expects a 8-byte argument, but you are passing a 4-byte argument (because char is promoted to int in a varargs list). There is no magic casting from the variadic arguments to the "expected type" of the format specifier. The behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Martin R Got it. Thanks. I didn't think deep enough I guess.

Comment: The first output is strange: `FFFFF` are *20* bits ...

Comment: @Martin R I am sorry . There is a typo here. The first output has only 4 F's i.e. it is 32 1's in binary. I am correcting the post again. Sorry guyz.

Comment: @Samboy786: But `FFFF` are 16 bits, not 32. (And `0000FFFF` are 32 bits, not 64.)

Comment: @MartinR ... yet another correction. Thanks for highlighting again. I was really tired but i hope you did understand the problem

Answer (score 3):

The `p` specifier of `printf` expects a `void *`. Instead, you're passing an `int` (exercise: why is it an `int`?), therefore the behaviour is undefined. Use a correct specifier for what you want to print (`c`, `x` or `u`, perhaps?).

Comment: But how does this actually work if i give it a void* type ptr. AFAIK i can modify any data that is of type void* (accept for copying from one place to another). I have tried giving it %x - it only truncates the leading 0's in the 32/64 bit field. I am also pretty sure that changing the typcast mostly doesn't change the data at all (it happens only in the rarest cases of DS).

Answer (score 1):

`%p` and `*ptr` not behaving as OP expects.

```
printf("\na[0]=%p",*ptr); // print the values at the next 4 memory locations
```

`ptr` has the value of address of `int n`.  Note: The type of `ptr` is *still* a pointer to a `char`.  `*ptr` says to dereference `ptr` getting a `char`.  This `char` has the 8-bit value of 0xFF as it is one of the bytes of `n`, which is certainly 0xFFFFFFFF (-1).  This `char` is promoted to an `int` as it is a varidac parameter to `printf()`.  Thus 0xFF becomes 0xFFFFFFFF as `int` is likely a 4-byte integer on your machine.  `printf()` sees the `%p` format specifier, thus expecting to see a 4-byte pointer in "VisualC++ '12".  So that is you output.  On "x64", an 8-byte pointer is expected, but only 4 bytes are defined (the 0xFFFFFFFF).  The next 4 byte it grabbed are undefined but turn out to be 0x00000000.  Thus you get "00000000FFFFFFFF".

The next line `printf("\na[1]=%p",*(ptr+1))` simple gets the next `char` of `n`, which is also 0xFF.  And then the same promotion to `int` with a value of 0xFFFFFFFF occurs.

Suspect the OP wants

```
printf("\na[0] = 0x%08X",*  ((int *)ptr)  ); // print the values at the next 4 memory locations
```